# Дополняемые TV с ценами

Tags: modx

Доброго дня!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, столкнулся с такой задачей — есть каталог мебели, соответственно у каждого шкафа есть некоторые свойства/характеристики, некоторые характеристики влияют на стоимость ( в дальнейшем планируется эти данные передавать в конструктор шкафа). Как проще всего реализовать ТВ-поля с стоимостью (соответственно для каждой опции каждого отдельного шкафа она будет разная.

На ум приходит только msOptionsPrice2, но не совсем комфортно каждый раз создавать модификации, тем более что многие из них на стоимость совершенно не влияют.

Есть ли решение?

Спасибо.